# Google Maps v3 Remove Infowindow from Certain Marker Types

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm loading a Google Map on my page that shows three types of marker. Master, Sub, and Minor. I want to have infowindows available on the Master & Sub types but not on the Minor type which should just be a static marker.

Is there any way to accomplish this?

I'm pretty much using this: https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlajax_v3?hl=it verbatim, with a few changes to the information and icons that get loaded.

I can't seem to find anything in the Maps API documentation that mentions doing something like this.

Comment: Yes, there is a way to accomplish it.  What have you tried?

Comment: I don't even know what TO try. I've been trying to search out an answer all morning to no avail. I'm hoping to be pushed in the right direction here.

Answer (score 0):

Think of it as not adding an infowindow to those markers.  Modify the marker creation to not call the bindInfowindow function for those types of markers.

From the tutorial to which you linked, modified to not create infowindows for markers with type "Minor":

```
  for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
    var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");
    var type = markers[i].getAttribute("type");
    var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
        parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
        parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
    var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address;
    var icon = customIcons[type] || {};
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      position: point,
      icon: icon.icon
    });
    if (type != "Minor") {
      bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
    }
  }
```